# How do I convert a grid of ints inputted from a file to a grid of strings

Tags: c, file-io, grid, sudoku

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) 
{
  FILE* inFile = NULL; // File pointer
  const int Row = 9;
  const int Col = 9;
  char fname[Row][Col];
  printf("Enter a file Name;");
  gets(fname);

  inFile = fopen(fname, "r");

  if (inFile == NULL) 
  {
    printf("Could not open file myfile.txt.\n");
    return -1; // -1 indicates error
  }

  // Done with file, so close it
  fclose(inFile);

  int j;
  int k;
  int sudoku[Row][Col];
  for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {
      fscanf(inFile, "%1d", &sudoku[j][k]);
      printf("%d", sudoku[j][k]);
      if(((k + 1) % 3) == 0)
      {
        printf(" ");
      }
      else{}
    }
  }
```

> How would I write my grid as a string. That could be used to print the grid when needed.
>   For example, if we take the grid convert it to a string and print

Comment: Side note: `char fname[Row][Col];` is wrong. Finding out why is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You forgot `#include <stdio.h>`, and you should compile with all warnings enabled (-Wall for gcc).

Comment: `gets()` is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first obvious solution is to create grid using some kind of DSV (delimeter separated values) eg.:

```
3,4,6 \n //OR ;
3,9,0 \n //OR ;
1,2,3 \n //OR ;
```

If you want variable size of the grid apart from modifying the code to use dynamic memory you should prefix the data with some kind of header:

```
[3,3]: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then you know the count of the items and can separate the simple string after column count.